# unable to create Sqlite Data base in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a data base in my project. but after sucessfully run the app Db is not created. I check it in file Explorer of DDMS but its  not creating. But the same code of Database cration is working in another project in that project db is created after app runs.. My db creation code is http://ge.tt/9pfqTl62/v/0?c
 Any one please help me. why it happens in this project only? Why it works in other project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android sqlite data base is creates when the first call made to gerReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabse() but not when the application is installed. So make sure you called one of those methods atleast once then check in the file explorer for the db file.